# Is it secure if I remove any custom authorization attribute from a ChildActionOnly action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net MVC 5 web application. And I have defined a custom authorized attribute for my application, as follow:-

```
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Approve", Model = "Customer")]
```

Which define that the user should have Approve permission on the customer controller.

Now I have multiple action methods that can be called using `Html.Action` only, where each action method return a partial view and I want these action methods to always have the same permission as their parent action method.

So it is secure if I remove the custom authorization attribute from these child action methods and define a `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute, so in this case I can ensure that these action methods will always be called as a child action methods and the parent action method will have the required permission? So on certain scenarios the ChildActionOnly action might be called with read permission while on other scenarios it can be called with Edit permission etc ?

Answer (score 1):

I use this pattern, and I believe it is secure.

The `[ChildActionOnly]` actions cannot be called directly, so they will always be protected by their parent actions' `[Authorize]` attribute. They do not need their own, unless you want to enforce stricter or different security on the child than the parent action.

The only risks I can see, is that you forget that the child action is not secured, and call it from a unsecured parent action, or you forget to annotate an unsecured child with `[ChildActionOnly]`. A "belt and braces" approach can sometimes be good when it comes to security - putting `[Authorize]` and `[ChildActionOnly]` on the child action protects you from programmer error.

Comment: so i only need to define [Authorize] just in case i forget to protect the parent ,,, not because i have to do so ? second question,, will hacker users be able to directly call ChildActionOnly action method ?

Comment: Yes - or because you want to enforce stricter security on the child action (different from the parent).

Comment: another question ,,, let say that i am passing a parameter along with the Html.Action as follow "@Html.Action("GetChildRecords", "Customer", new  {customerid = Model.CustomerID})</div>" to show all the child records for a cusomter,, then will it be possible for a hacker to modify the customerid parameter and in this case to view the child details for another customer ???